# Is it possible to create a single list, and have filtered views of it on different pages?

Tags: 2010, list, view

I have an out-of-the-box SharePoint 2010 site and want to implement a Knowledge Base in the form of a simple list. This should be straight-forward.

However, if I have a column in the list, say 'Appliance', can I then have an Appliance-specific version of the list on another page, i.e.

- the list only displays list entries where the Appliance is a hard-coded type, e.g. 'Washing Machine'
- the Appliance column is not shown
- when adding a new entry, the Appliance field is set to 'Washing Machine' and is not shown

That last point is not essential, but if the Appliance field is shown then it should default to 'Washing Machine'

So one 'master' list, but several views on different Appliance-specific pages

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to create 3 Views.

1. In first view filter Appliance by "Washing Machine" value.
   [image]
2. In the second view uncheck appliance column.
3. For the third option you have to set Appliance column default value to 'Washing Machine', you can do this from Appliance column setting. now create the view and uncheck the Appliance column from view settings. select this view in list view webpart and then add script editor webpart on same page. write css for hiding "New Item" button.

To add a created list view on new page use following steps:

1. Edit the page where you want to add webpart.
2. Click on Insert tab and then click on WebPart.
3. In the webpart list in a first folder "Apps" there will be your list available, select that and click "Add" button, it will add list view webpart on page.
4. Now go to webpart setting and there you can change the list view.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.

It is possible to create a list and add multiple filtered view of it on different SharePoint pages.

The last point you mentioned is bit tricky which will not be possible using out of the box capabilities of SharePoint. You might need to write some client side code for that.

Also note that the list forms will be same on all the list web parts added in SharePoint page.

**References**:

1. [Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9#OfficeVersion=2016,_2013,_2010).
2. [How to add a list view webpart to a page?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28537f90-5c3c-47dc-920b-3ce91d6547f1/how-to-add-a-list-view-webpart-to-a-page-sharepoint-2013)